# Need to match from json only values with quotes using regex

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm trying to match all values from any json. 
My regex right now is `/: ('|").*?('|")(?=,)?/g`
I need to get only value with qoutes, but getting colon also.
https://www.regextester.com/99141 
Any tips?

Comment: My question is very simple. Need to match from json only values with quotes using regex. And yes, using regex. I'm using rainbow.js and need to change color of all values. in html i get json file, so need to match all value and add classes.

Answer (score 0):

Took some doing, but I think this seems to [pass the tests I've thrown at it](https://regexr.com/420el):

```
/("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")(?=,|\s*(]|}))/g
```

It appears workable on both minified and prettified JSON strings.